# split string within react if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have json data for order.expeditionPlaces which is formatted like:

`"expeditionPlaces": "Place1, Place2",`

I am trying to split this so that it will display each place on a new line and I also need to be able to check if it is null

`Place1`

`Place2`

`{order.expeditionPlaces.split(",").join("<br />")}` threw an error when it received a null value.

I'm not sure what the best approach to this is, I've tried split and join on the object itself and also tried to put it into `const Split` but it doesn't like this, I'm not sure where it should go within the if statement?

```
if (this.state.possibleOrders && this.state.possibleOrders.length > 0) {
        this.state.possibleOrders.forEach((order, index) => {
            possibleOrders.push(<tr key={index}>
                <td>{order.orderId}</td>
                <td><Button bsStyle="success">{order.sortingTableName}</Button></td>
                <td>{Split}</td>
                <td>{order.expeditionPlaces.split(",").join("<br />")}</td>
                <td>{order.sortingBufferPlaces}</td>
            </tr>);

            const Split = if (order.expeditionPlaces.length >0) {order.expeditionPlaces.split(",").join("<br />")}}
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this

```
{order.expeditionPlaces.split(",").join("<br />")}
```

With

```
{order.expeditionPlaces ? order.expeditionPlaces.split(",").join("<br />") : ''}
```

Comment: @ThomasHarrison Please accept the answer if it worked